# How to connect a wireless wifi network?

Tags: networking, wireless

I can't connect a wireless network wifi network in **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**
I followed some tutorials on the internet and not working! Can anyone help me?

I'm a really noob  and new to this os! Please help me! As described in Ubuntu Desktop Guide>>Networking,web & email>>Wireless Networking>>Connect to a wireless network there is no thing as **Wifi Not Connected** in right side of top bar! What to do? Help me!!

Here is the screenshot:
[image: Here is the Screenshot]

Here is the result when i run `sudo lshw -c network` in terminal,

*-network
description: Ethernet interface
product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
logical name: eno1
version: 15
serial: f4:39:09:74:75:46
capacity: 1Gbit/s
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1104000-b1104fff memory:b1100000-b1103fff
*-network UNCLAIMED
description: Network controller
product: RTL8821CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
version: 00
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
configuration: latency=0
resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1000000-b100ffff

Comment: I can see you have Bluetooth is there a hardware switch that turns off the wireless adapter? Make and model of the laptop please. Also I see you are on battery lets be on power while you troubleshoot.

Comment: I saw this but no works because i'm not seeing WIFI NOT CONNECTED that's why i'm asking it here

Comment: If there is no adapter for what ever reason it will not say not connected as there is noting to connect.

Comment: @user535733 i update the question! I just run `sudo lshw -c network` and other one is not working!

Comment: Please note that the wireless device is shown as UNCLAIMED. That means that it requies but does not yet have an appropriate driver. Follow the process in the duplicate to install the driver.